# Pin functionality multiplexing in NXP p1010 processor

Tags: switches, design

I am trying to make a small design using P1010 processor.

---

During power-up sequence processor fetches configuration through specific pins.

All of them are also used for other functionality.
The processor guide told us we have two options here.

- First - use a PLD device (CPLD specifically).
- The second one in to use pull-up and pull-down resistors. I don't
  need a PLD flexibility now so I will plan to use resistors.

I will write about a specific pins here but generaly it is the same for all of them.

**First question:**

We have two pins. One of them is EC_MDC/cfg_cpu_boot. The second is READY/
TRIG_OUT. READY: Asserted-indicates that the device has completed the reset operation, and e500 core is not in a power-down state (nap, doze, or sleep).
I need some kind of sheematics here so while READY is 0 the porcessor should use resistor (pullup or pull down). But when READY goes 1 it should use EC_MDC functionality (go to other part of the scematics and bypass resistor)

**Second question is almost the same.**

We have some pins wich have triple mennings. Something like IFC_CLK_1/USB_NXT/IFC_CS_3_B. We will switch between them using software. But how should we rote this pinn in such a way that we use different part of schemes and completely bypassing others.

For example IFC_CLK_1 is used as a clock during some operations for one part of scematics. At the other time we would like to use IFC_CS_3_B as chip select for completly different part of schematics.

So generally, how can we use pins for different activities represented by different and unrelated same parts?

Comment: https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-39684/l/freescale-reference-manual-for-p1010-qoriq-integrated-processor

Comment: Yes. the official link is http://www.nxp.com/products/software-and-tools/hardware-development-tools/embedded-board-solutions-ebs/qoriq-p1010-and-p1014-low-power-communications-processors-with-trust-architecture:P1010?tab=Documentation_Tab
But I think it is not really needed as the question is more conceptual then proccessor specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a pretty broad question.

So, most microcontrollers have some way, typically some control registers, that you can use in your firmware to change the functionality of a pin.

Now, if you need to "multiplex" that pin to different signals/elements of your circuitry, you'll need some kind of multiplexing.

In case of digital signals, that might simply be some transistors that you address with another pin; in case of analog signals, or *fast* digital signals, this might be a bit more complicated and need specific analog switches – whether those are discrete-transistor-based, based e.g. on analog switch ICs (e.g. from [TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/switches-multiplexers/analog-switch-products.page?keyMatch=analog%20switches&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything#), or [ST](http://www.st.com/en/switches-and-multiplexers/analog-switch-multiplexers.html). Basically, go to any semiconductor manufacturer's website, and search for "analog switch") , or even relays, completely and utterly depends on your application. Furthermore, you'll still need some output to program these multiplexing devices – and that will require more output pins, and it seems you're already in a situation where these are sparse.

Generally, I kind of feel like you're doing something wrong: If you already use a relatively large microcontroller, just use one with even more pins, and simply have one pin for each part of your schematic. If you can't do that, find the digital outputs or inputs that you don't need to switch/read fast, and attach them to some sort of IO extender – be it a simple shift register, or some kind of I²C-connected IO-extender IC, or a CPLD, or something connected to some high-speed bus, or any other way of using few pins to provide many IO pins.

Comment: Can you please add more information about analog switches or relays? Specifically, some examples or may be famous IC models. Keywords to "google" the pictures would be fine too.

Comment: Not adding a link to relays, because you know what a relay is (or you should look it up on wikipedia); I added links to analog switches, but really, I just searched for "analog switch" on TI.com and St.com...